# Does extra RAM improve performance when running VMs?

Tags: virtual-machine, ram

I am running a Linux VM on Windows 7, and experience extreme slowness when using the VM. Is this because of a lack of memory? I thought VM's leveraged primarily compute cores and drive space (HDD/SSD).

I am looking at getting a new Surface device and need to know whether memory is critical to running VMs. Unfortunately VMWare hasn't been very helpful: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008360. Please advise.

Comment: Look at your RAM usage in your VM.  If most RAM in the Linux VM is allocated (not counting buffers), check your disk IO (e.g. iostat).  If you see frequent IO to a swap file, adding RAM will likely improve the speed of your VM.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because might belong on Super User, but there's not enough detail in the question for it to be answerable over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four main bottlenecks with respect to VMs in my experience:

1. CPU
2. Memory
3. Disk IO Throughput
4. Network throughput

### CPU

CPUs will be taxed and cause performance issues if your VMs are working constantly at computing. IO (Input/Output) usually doesn't factor into this it is more about computation time on the processor for your applications. You will need more CPU if you are doing tasks like:

- computing large numbers
- video/photo editing
- Video Games

### Memory

Memory is a very common bottleneck as each machine will need a set amount to host the OS. Windows usually uses more for this than Linux and the like. Also, If you are running applications which are storing large amounts of data in memory like:

- Some Databases
- video playback
- video/photo editing
- Video Games

### Disk Throughput

While disk storage space is becoming incredibly cheap, there is still a finite amount of throughput (the amount of data it can send/receive at once) available. You will notice more lag here if you are running a low-RPM disk like a 5200 RPM drive, if you are experiencing lag (especially during boot) your best bang for your buck will usually be in a solid-state hard drive.

### Network Throughput

If your VMs are reaching out to the network or handling a lot of network requests (like a server), you may notice some lag, but this will not usually affect the other factors, so your lag would usually be noticed only in page load times. If this is a problem, I have invested in a NIC (Network Interface Card) which has four gigabit network interfaces. This ran me about $250 about a year ago, and it has allowed my servers to keep up with a couple of medium traffic websites. I believe any lag my users experience are usually on my ISPs end (only 25 Mb service is available in my area).